# How to use nodemailer for custom domain emails

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am making a website and I'm using Nodemailer for Signup verification. For sending the emails. I am using email ***example@gmail.com***. Now I want to use custom domain email to send emails (i.e. ***example@gla.ac.in***). But Nodemailer is giving error **"host not found"**. Can someone please tell me that how can I fix this error?

Comment: Please have a look at this example from [github](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/examples/full.js)

Answer (score 1):

first make webmail for your domain make sure you have webmail service from web hosting provider. call to node mailer function define configuration

```
     var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                     host: "mail.domain.com",
                     port: 465,
                     secure: true,
                     auth: {
                           user: from,
                            pass: password
                            },
                      tls: {
                            rejectUnauthorized: false
                           }
                   });
```

now set up mail options

```
        var mailOptions = {
                                from: from,
                                to: to,
                                subject: subject,
                                 html:'your html code here',

                         attachments: [

                                      {
                                        // file on disk as an attachment
                                        filename: attachment,
                                        path: domain-address/file-name
                                      },
                                    ]
                                   };
```

finally, send your email and log response

```
    ransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                      if (error) {
                             console.log(error);
                       } else {
                         console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                       }
               });
```